# How can I align an AdView below a ListView, both contained by FrameLayout

Tags: android

The code below puts the AdView on top of the ListView, but what I want is to have the AdView at the bottom of the screen and the ListView to take up the rest of the screen.

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/lst_viw_bg"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:scrollingCache="false"
            android:animationCache="false" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminate="true" >
        </ProgressBar>

    </FrameLayout>


    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want it to be as in the right side of the image below:

[image]

Changing FrameLayout to RelativeLayout causes my application to crash when populating the ListView with the following crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1722)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1667)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:373)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2174)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1315)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1512)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1199)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6383)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1259)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayout make your view can superposition each others. I think you should change to use RelativeLayout:

1 - Change FrameLayout to RelativeLayout

2 - Adding this param to AdView and ProgressBar: android:layout_below="@+id/listView"

Comment: Thank you but changing FrameLayout to RelativeLayout causes my application to crash when I try to populate the ListView, I added the crash log in the question

Comment: You should change in both XML and .java file . The error is:
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.

Your code still define the Layout is FrameLayout. In java file (The Activity contain ListView) you should change from Frame to Relative also .